# Jquery and Wikipedia API user agent problem

Tags: jquery, user-agent, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

i'm trying to use the wikipedia api, but i read that is necessary to send a non generic user-agent...

i'm using jquery with ajax call...but i dont know what to do to make it working....

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a script that makes requests at a human rate, you should be fine. The browser with Jquery will send an appropriate user agent, and it probably cannot be reliably overridden.

The ["don't copy a browser" User-Agent requirement](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/User-Agent_policy) is aimed at automated editing processes that generate a large number of page requests at a high rate of speed. If you're trying to write one of *those* in Javascript inside a browser, you might want to look into other solutions.